# conver Sub Query and CASE to Django ORM

Tags: django, orm

I am using MS SQL SERVER as Django DATABASE (using pyodbc django module)

There are two tables, item and favorite item

How to convert following query to Django ORM

```
SELECT item_id,
    CASE WHEN 
        item_id IN (SELECT item_id FROM FavoriteItem WHERE user_id='test_user')
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END as is_favorite_item 
FROM Item
```

Two models already define in models.py as ItemModel and FavoriteItemModel

I know there are some alternative ways that using 'raw', '@property decoration' and others to solve this problem.

However, I'd like to know if there is a chance to solve this problem using pure Django ORM.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Answer by myself.

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value, BooleanField

favorite_items = FavoriteItem.objects.filter(user_id='test_user')
items = Item.objects.annotate(
          is_favorite_item=Case(
            When(item_id__in=favorite_items.values('item_id'), then=True),
          default=Value(False),
          output_field=BooleanField()))
```